# XCode test coverage reports uncovered line with only braces

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, sonarqube, test-coverage

I have the code below:

```swift
var property: Type {
  if condition {
    return value1
  } else {
    return value2
  }
}
```

and I have unit tests coverage both the `if` and `else` conditions, however, XCode coverage reports that the last line isn't covered, where there's only a `}`.

[image: SonarQube report]

Report from SonarQube, which depends on the coverage report from XCode.

I haven't tried if I write it in this way, if its still reported as uncovered:

```swift
var property: Type {
  if condition {
    return value1
  }
  return value2
}
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Test coverage is not a golden solution to all problems. Achieving a 100% test coverage does not mean you will have bug free software. In this case I’d just accept that the software works his way. It might be a bug with the coverage calculation. ‍♂️ Playing around with the code to satisfy a code coverage calculation is not going to make the code more or less correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are possible variants:

a) preferred one (IMO)

```
var property: Type {
  condition ? value1 : value2
}
```

b) and if you like explicit branches (or last your snapshot)

```
var property: Type {
  var result = value2
  if condition {
    result = value1
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if the two variants resolve the code coverage issue, is it a lesson or something that indicates the `if…else…` statement should be avoided when possible, at least the code coverage tool thinks this way?

Comment: No, in you first variant there is 3 return points and command pointer never got to 3d, so code coverage shows that correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi good to know, looks like the coverage tool isn't smart enough to consider `else` with a `return` in it as the last return point.